# Getting the Textbox Value from A MasterPage Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox, master-pages

I have a MasterPage Master and I want to set a Textbox value on this page instead of individually on the child pages. I want to do it this way so that it functions across the site for a newsletter signup. Currently, when I postback to the server, the textbox comes back with an empty string. How can I capture the value of the textbox in this scenerio?

Here's a code sample:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPageLO.master.cs" Inherits="masterpages_MasterPageLO" %>

<asp:Textbox runat="server" EnableViewState= "true" id="email" name="email" CSSclass="form-control required" placeholder="Enter your Email"></asp:textbox>

<asp:Linkbutton runat="server" ID="btnemail" name="btnemail" CSSclass="btn btn-success"  OnClick="btnemail_Click">Subscribe</asp:Linkbutton>
```

and email.TextBox after post is equal to "" but not null which is strange.

Comment: Put the button on the master also and handle the click there. But if you show how you handle the signup it would be easier to help.

Comment: That is what I tried and it is giving me the empty string value when I set string email = Email.Textbox on the button click event

Comment: But where is the method? On the master or on the page, and the TextBox itself?

Comment: I updated the question with more info. I hope it helps. The code is in the master not the child page.

Comment: If it is "" then it would seem you reset the value on page load somewhere. Maybe forgot an `IsPostBack` check somewhere?

Comment: No, that is not the case. I have a button click event that captures the value and it comes back as "" instead of the value of the textbox. Maybe I will try the IsPostback check and see if that helps

Comment: So, I tried if (IsPostback) then set a session variable and it was still empty string but not null which is strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the post logic and moving most of it out of the Master MasterPage and implemented a solution utilizing the child Page(s)/Master combination and also utilizing JQUERY/AJAX to get the value of the textbox and then inserting it into the Database because the Master textbox kept losing its value after redirecting to the Default.aspx page when using the codebehind for that file. I also borrowed some of the logic from: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-Form-Data-to-Database-with-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx to suit my needs and now everything works the way I want it to.